# Rails 3 nested form with devise fields not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, I have reviewed all of the similar questions on SO but nothing seems to work.

I have the following form

registrations/new.html.erb

```
      <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_roles do |builder| %> 
      <%= builder.hidden_field :role_id, :value => @role.id %>
    <% end %>
```

I have overridden the registrations controller like so

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  layout "public"

  def new 

    @user = User.new
    @user.user_roles.build()
    @role = Role.find_by_name("organiser")
    super
  end
```

The view does not render the hidden form, if I remove the f variable then the fields for user_roles are rendered.

I am building a placeholder instance of user_roles in the new action but this does not seem to make any difference. I have set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles`.

Anyway this is driving me to distraction, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue but I am not sure why it works. (changes surrounded with **)

in the view I have

```
    <%= f.fields_for **:user_roles, @user_roles** do |builder| %> 
      <%= builder.hidden_field :role_id, :value => @role.id %>
    <% end %>
```

in my devise registrations controller in the new action, I have

```
  def new 
    @user = User.new
    **@user_roles = [@user.user_roles.build ]**
    @role = Role.find_by_name("organiser")
    super
  end
```

My use case is as follows, I want the people who register on the site to be in the organisers role, they can then add other users to the system in either the suppliers or members role. To handle creating users inside the application I have a users controller that allows an organiser to add the user to a specific role.

The code in new action for the users_controller is:

```
  def new
    @user = @wedding.users.new
    @roles = @wedding.roles
    1.times{ @user.user_roles.build() }
  end
```

the nested form in users/new.html.haml is:

```
    = f.fields_for :user_roles do |builder| 
      %p
        = f.label :roles
        = builder.select(:role_id, options_for_select(@roles.map {|role| [role.name, role.id]}))
```

the problem is this code works and when I tried to copy it in the registrations controller it didn't work. I can't figure out why, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Hope this is helpful.